# Rails 4.0 install error -require: cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I installed the new Ruby (2.0) and Rails 4.0 and when i do "Rails new test_app" i get the following.
Anybody run into this?

[devuser@devbox ~]$ rails new test_app

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such >file -- active_support (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/generators.rb:4:in >`<top (required)>'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties->4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:28:in`'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top >(required)>'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/bin/rails:7:in`'
>     from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
>     from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in`'

Comment: Did you try rails 4.0.0.rc1 instead?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I found my problem was permission related(see answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was permission related. Somehow, the "other" user  needs rx permissions.
I did the following and it works now:

sudo chmod -R o+rx /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/

If you getting cannot load such file and its pointing to require statement, check your permissions for /gems folder and folders underneat.

Comment: Rvm/rbenv users don't have such problems. Just try one of them.

Comment: I'm using rvm and I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Create an gemset and use it in rvmrc.

Then come out of the project using Cd ../

Again enter into project, this time it will show,
"RVM has encountered a new or modified .rvmrc file in the current directory"

Type 'Yes'.

and now give bundle install.

It will work.