# Beginning Ruby on Rails in Linux Mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, sublimetext2

This may sound very basic to many of you. I have just started a Ruby on Rails tutorial in Linux. I'm very new to the Linux OS. I have installed a rvm. But I am unable to install Rails. It's saying "cant load such file --zlib". And I can see two source files for Ruby. Not sure if I have two Ruby installed.

Comment: is it rails project to print hello world on web or just ruby code to print hello world ?

Comment: yes.. hello world on web

Comment: just open up terminal `(ALT+CTRL+T)` change directory to your project `cd path/to/project` , and do `rails s`

Comment: raj@raj-Inspiron-N5010 ~/Desktop/ruby $ rails s

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from /usr/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

got this error

Comment: see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326439/rails-4-0-install-error-require-cannot-load-such-file-active-support-loade http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452652/ruby-on-rails-error-making-new-app-rb55in-require posts

Answer (score 2):

Just take a note that you have selected  the correct build system:

`"Tools -> Build System -> Ruby"`

Then press `CTRL+B`. 
This should work.

Comment: thanks.. i did that and ran the file.. but giving an error
/home/raj/Desktop/ruby/rails.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `helloworld' for main:Object (NameError)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/raj/Desktop/ruby/rails.rb"]
[dir: /home/raj/Desktop/ruby]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/raj/.rvm/bin]
do i hav to be careful about the location of my file?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `.rb` file in sublime using  `ctrl + b`.

Comment: rails new hello 
is giving me an error..
/home/raj/Desktop/ruby/rails.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `helloworld' for main:Object (NameError)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/raj/Desktop/ruby/rails.rb"]
[dir: /home/raj/Desktop/ruby]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/raj/.rvm/bin]
do i have to be careful about where i create my file?

Comment: Will you please show your code ? or you can ask new question for this error.

Comment: This `rails new helloworld` command uses for create new rails application with `helloworld` name and you should execute this in command prompt or terminal. Please go through the official website of rails and get some knowledge that how to create new basic rails application and move forward. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: it seems rails is not properly installed. i am unable to install using gem install rails.. gives the following error     ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are a bit confused about how Ruby on Rails work.
Sumblime can run your ruby code but not on Rails stack.
My suggestion it's to work always with an open terminal on the directory of your rails application.
Let's assume you created a new rails project as

```
rails new helloWorld
```

The rails generetor will create a subfolder helloWorld.This will be your working directory in the terminal.
So you have to do:

```
cd helloWorld
```

and then

```
rails s
```

It will run your rails application on an embedded server on localhost:3000 by default.

Comment: it seems rails is not properly installed. when i rub rails --version,i get the following error.. i am unable use gem install rails..
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)

Comment: gem install rails give error             ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

What method did you use to install ruby?

If you compiled from source you may need to do

```
   sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

And then recompile ruby

Otherwise, you may not have the most recent version of Rubygems

Try:
 go to https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.2.3

download rubygems-update-2.2.3.gem

call the directory where the file was dl'ed, then

```
   gem install rubygems-update-2.2.3.gem

   update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc

   rubygems --version #Should show 2.2.3

   gem install rails
```

Comment: The first half of this solution came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947586/installing-rails-with-gem-error-loading-command-install-undefined-method-in

Comment: Alternatively, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1d6rnWRb_7k&list=PLDmvslp_VR0xlwr5lAx2PDsZLu7oIOhpX&index=4) walks you through installing rails on linux

Comment: the problem i think is I have two ruby locations. i used the downloaded file from the source and rvm.
/usr/local/bin/ruby &
/usr/bin/ruby                                                          
how do i uninstall one? is there any general command uninstall in linux?

Comment: Judging by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11536137/4861201) (which will also explain how to uninstall if that's what you want) those directories may be part of the same installation. Did you try  
       sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
? Followed by recompiling

Comment: If you go with the uninstall, you may just want to follow the video I linked on your next try

Comment: [And here's some info on two ways to remove packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118880/should-i-use-apt-get-remove-or-apt-get-purge)

Comment: i tried sudo apt-get install libssl-dev then recompiled by rvm reinstall --disable-binary 2.1 .. it giving an error sayin "command gem pristine --extensions  --version ' failed, you need to fix this gems manually."